# Per-user Chrome/Chromium Plank/Docky icon?

Tags: google-chrome, docky

I've been using [Plank](https://launchpad.net/plank) as a primary dock.

I was able to get individual webpages to inhabit their own plank icon by:

<kbd>Menu</kbd>  -> <kbd>More Tools...</kbd>  -> <kbd>Create Application Shortcuts</kbd>,

then adding the generated .desktop file to plank.

When I need to focus back on my browser I'll often use the mouse-wheel to browse over the open chrome windows. Which is time consuming and a bit annoying when User2's chrome window is focused, and then gets set in the alt+tab history, I've just lived with it.

I would like to be able to instantly focus on User1's chrome window, or User2's chrome window with two individual icons in the plank dock.

How can I create plank/docky launchers that will focus/open a specific users chrome window(s)?